javascript change option in function call
I have on my discord bot with discord.js v14 this npm installed: discord-tts.
If i run that function all is fine but i like to change the language from "en" to "de-DE".
Here is the function from the file:
function getVoiceStream(text, {lang = 'en', slow = false, host = 'https://translate.google.com', timeout = 10000, splitPunct} = {}) {
    const stream = new Stream.PassThrough();
    downloadFromInfoCallback(stream, text, {lang, slow, host, timeout, splitPunct });
    return stream;
}

And thats my call:
const stream=discordTTS.getVoiceStream(newState.member.displayName.split('[')[1].split(']')[1] + ' gekommen');

I expect to: Set the parameter lang: to "de-DE".
I tried follow command:
const stream=discordTTS.getVoiceStream(newState.member.displayName.split('[')[1].split(']')[1] + ' gegangen', lang="de-DE");


The function accepts an optional object with properties (using destructuring in the parameter list), so the second argument should be {lang: "de-DE"}, like this: const stream=discordTTS.getVoiceStream(newState.member.displayName.split('[')[1].split(']')[1] + ' gegangen', {lang: "de-DE"});

Thanks, I also tried this, but get this error: Error: lang "de-DE" might not exist

Here is a link to the full code of the function: https://github.com/mundoex/discord-tts/blob/master/index.js

That error suggests that the code I showed above works, but the language may not be defined. That's a completely different issue to what the original question asks.

Try a 2-letter language code (de) as suggested here

This is now running:
const stream=discordTTS.getVoiceStream(newState.member.displayName.split('[')[1].split(']')[1] + ' gegangen', {lang: "de"});

Big thank's for all the Help!!
